# Strange behaviour Python generator with recursivity

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I very recently worked on an algorithm made to list spanning trees on a digraph for Sagemath.

Doing so, my colleague and I found a strange behaviour we didn't fully understand.

For spec aspect, Sagemath is using Python 2.7 and `import absolute import from __future__`.

The algorithm lists the spanning trees one by one, using the "yield" keyword with recursive calls on itself. 
At one point, we make tests before the recursive call to ensure that it doesn't trigger an error.

BUT, if we remove the tests and let the algorithm generate an error, without catching it, the generator does not stop itself but passes to the next recursive call.

If I can give an illustrated explanation, let's say there's 3 steps in each recursive call and we got something like this:

- level 0 - step 1
- level 0 - step 2

  - level 1 - step 1
  - level 1 - step 2

    - level 2 - step 1 <- the error happen here but do not stop the generation
  - level 1 - step 3

    - level 2 - step 1
    - level 2 - yield
      -level 0 - step 3
- ...

If we catch the error with a "try catch" then, the algorithm will stop itself.

I let the code here; I'm not sure you can catch everything if you don't know Sagemath but most of it is understandable. I will make specific comment to highlight the interesting part and remove some parts of the code.

I wish someone could explain me this behaviour; it's like generator object could handle exception during recursive call and ignore them while generating.

```
def _rec_spanning_trees():
        if len(list_merged_edges) == self.order()-1: # CONDITION TO YIELD
            for indexes in product(*list_merged_edges):
                yield DiGraph([list_edges[index] for index in indexes], format='list_of_edges', pos=self.get_pos())

        # part removed

        # THIS HERE !
        # "outgoing_edge_iterator" is raising an error if D does not have any edges
        s, x, l = D.outgoing_edge_iterator(source).next()

        # HERE ! 
        # If I remove the "if(len(...." then the line above will raise an error sometime, but do not if I let it
        D.delete_edge(s, x, l)
        if len(list(D.depth_first_search(source))) == D.order():
           for tree in _rec_spanning_trees():
               yield tree
        D.add_edge(s, x, l)

        # part removed

        for tree in _rec_spanning_trees():
            yield tree

        # part removed
```

Comment: Show us the complete, exact error message.

Comment: + how your code is called - so we'll be able to repro

Comment: @user2357112 that's the point, there is no error, the generator seems to handle it.

Comment: @alfasin This code is an intern function of a class' method but user2357112 gave an answer that seems quite good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D.outgoing_edge_iterator(source).next()` produces an exception, sure, but that exception is `StopIteration`. This is the exception used to signal the end of an iterator, and when it propagates out of your generator and up to the `for` loop above, the `for` loop takes it to mean that the loop is done.

This behavior has been [changed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) in more recent Python versions; a `StopIteration` raised inside a generator will now be converted to a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Oh ! Ok ! So is it ok to assume that it will stay that way and is it a good way to do it ? Removing this "if" makes the all algorithm faster

Comment: @XanX3601: I can't see your whole algorithm, but it looks to me like removing the condition makes your algorithm wrong; it looks like if you remove that condition, your algorithm may start generating disconnected subgraphs instead of just spanning trees.

Comment: Sage already includes a [spanning tree generation function](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html#sage.graphs.graph.Graph.spanning_trees), so you could probably use that. If you specifically need an iterator (Sage's function produces a list), basing your code off of Sage's code may be a good way to go about it.

Comment: Our tests show that it work with or without it. The code is simpler to read with it but the order in which we do the operations prevent having disconnected subgraphs. So it is more a question of clarity over performance now. I'll transmit your answer to the people working on it with me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: yea, Sagemath does have a method but only for undirected graphs and we need one for directed ones which have less method, being less used than undirected graphs